# Upload image file from Android Device to Laravel API

Tags: android, laravel, react-native

I build the app using React-Native and I created API in Laravel for that project. Now when I install app on android phone using generated apk file I can't save image files to S3 storage.

When I work locally on ios and android simulators and also send file using Postman everything works great, but in physical android device it doesn't save the image and not catch any error.

There is my controller method code:

```
public function updatePhoto(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $userEmail = $request->userEmail;
            $filename = 'userPhotos/' . time() . '-' . $request->fileName . ".jpg";

            Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, file_get_contents($request->file));
            Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($filename, 'public');

            $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);

            $updateUserPhoto = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('email', $userEmail)
                    ->update(['photo_path' => $url]);

            $user = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('email', $userEmail)->get();

            return response()->json(['status' => 'OK', 'result' => $user]); 
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $user = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('email', $userEmail)->get();

            $this->storeErrorLog($user->id, '/updatePhoto', $e->getMessage());

            return response()->json(['status' => 'ERR', 'result' => $e->getMessage()]); 
        }
    }
```

Is anybody has similar issues with Laravel API? Maybe it's some android image data formatting? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: does you website has https enabled?

Comment: Yes and I use https:// in my Postman test requests and it works on Postman.

Comment: I notice in log that I get ' - - [19/Jul/2019:21:38:54 +0200] "POST //api/uploadUserPhoto HTTP/1.0" 500 33 "-" "okhttp"'. Is it wrong?

Comment: Since it's a 500 error, it means it did not work.

Comment: Can you post the content of your `laravel_dir/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: When I debug android locally I find error: "Unable to init from given url (file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1c9e0a73-711a-4a8e-85a0-d47daf156781.jpg)."